# Wordpress: Integrating Contact Form 7 and Ultimate Member or...?

Tags: php, wordpress, forms, plugins

I am trying to integrate two Wordpress plugins: Contact Form 7 and Ultimate Member...or come up with an alternate approach. I've already reached out to plugin support for UM, as I pay for their extensions. I include the info they offered below.

**What I want:**
To have an application form that creates a user and assigns a specific UM community role upon submission and allows easy export and viewing of the data from fields in the application form.

UM roles are a separate functionality from default WP user roles, although they can be synced.

**It seems like there are (at least) two approaches:**

1. *To somehow add code to the Contact Form 7 that would create an
   account and change user role on submission of the form.*

   I need this by specific form, not all forms.

   It looks like I would need to make CF7 function as a registration form as well as send to or set info for UM functionality? I found additional code on the UM GitHub site that integrates registration from Gravity Forms with UM roles...perhaps it could be altered to work with CF7? https://gist.github.com/ultimatemember/d98861b4c14a1540291b

   Here's what UM tech support offered (as they currently don't support 3rd party integration):

   - You need custom coding for adding user role by third party form. Its    quite easy, you can use this wordpress function to do so
     https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/update_user_meta.
     An example would be:

     ```
     update_user_meta($user_id, 'role', 'customer');
     ```

   Another thing I found in my research refers to a hook:

   ```
       wpcf7_before_send_mail
   ```

   Perhaps there is a way to use this to make the account and UM role before submission?

   I am not skilled enough with PHP (noobie here) to figure out the full implementation myself. Where would I put this in the plugin or theme php files (that would not be overwritten by future updates - can you make a "child" file for a plugin)? Does it go in the theme's functions.php? How would I customize to apply only to a specific Contact Form 7 form? What else would I need to be aware of in implementing this?

   This solution would allow me to use the export and user management capacities of Contact Form 7 and some add-on plugins, with which I'm already familiar.
2. *Alternately, to capture the user meta from UM registration forms in a usable format for export as csv file.*

   I can create a custom registration form in UM with my application fields that would create the UM community role and account. However, UM currently has no export function and seems to save user meta from custom fields in ways that some of the available export plugins don't recognize. All the data submitted by users is thus hard to extract in a way that can be tracked and looked at across multiple users.

Any suggestions or explanations of how to approach my application form that creates a UM account and community role would be so gratefully received!

Thanks for your time,
Jen

Comment: Your question is very detailed, but not relevant for the SO platform. I suggest hiring a freelancer with PHP and Wordpress skills.

Comment: @PhazePhusion Okay, thanks for your advice. I was hoping someone might be able to point me to ways to figure it out on my own from all these specifics...I'm trying to learn some of this as well while learning PHP. Obviously above my pay grade here! I'll look into some freelance advice...any suggestions on how to find someone reputable? I've never hired a developer...just taught myself.

Comment: @Jen Upwork is a great place to start when looking for freelancers.

Answer (score 0):

This is just a basic answer as i'm not php expert but if you want to try, maybe have a look at this : 
`add_action` or `add_filter`

Something like that :

```
add_action( 'wpcf7_before_send_mail', 'my_example_function' );
function my_example_function() {
    update_user_meta($user_id, 'role', 'customer');
}
```

Thi is just an example, sorry I can't help more.
Good luck !

Comment: Thanks, @Melk. I'm playing around with this to see if there is an easy solution!

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to use the plugin called Export User Data: https://wordpress.org/plugins/export-user-data/

You can then create a registration form with custom meta keys in ultimate member and select those meta keys in the export user data settings so only the ones you want will be exported to xls. No contact form 7 needed.